# Which rule was use to solve this series.

Tags: power-series

[image]

I am  only confused about the series part of this question.
The solution to that part was:

$2V^8+2V^{16}+....... =2 V^8/(1-V^8)$

How did they get this, is it a geometric series rule?

Comment: I did it in 2nd year, but I just was not connecting it to this until now. a=2V^8 and r=V^8

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The sum of the geometric series

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} ar^n$$

for $|r| < 1$ is given by

$$\frac{a}{1-r}$$

In your example, we have $a = 2V^8$ and $r = V^8$

See [Geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) for more information.

Comment: @Mi-leeWilson IMO the right way to thank on MSE is to upvote/accept answer.